# Two definitions for an operator, are consistent?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

I've two definitions for an operator but I can't figure out if they are equivalent (or if one implies the other).
We are on $\mathbb{R}$, let $A_g$ be the operator where $g$ is a function (I'm not asking for any regularity, if you need something you can assume it). The first definition is that $A_g$ is the operator for which
\begin{align}
\label{def1}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\xi x} A_g f(x) \,dx=g(i\xi) \tilde{f}(\xi), \quad \quad  (1)
\end{align}
where $\tilde{f}(\xi)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\xi x} f(x) \,dx$. So I know the Fourier transform of $A_g$.

Now I have an other definition for $A_g$, which is actually more an application:
\begin{align}
\label{def2}
A_g e^{-kt}=g(k)e^{-kt} \quad t>0, \quad \quad (2)
\end{align}
where $k$ could be a parameter or also a function (not in $t$). Are these two consistent?

An example: $g(x)=x^2$, trivially
\begin{align*}
\partial_t^2 e^{-kt}=(-k)^2 e^{-kt}= k^2 e^{-kt}= g(k) e^{-kt}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\xi x} \partial_x^2 f(x) \,dx=(i\xi)^2 \tilde{f}(\xi)=g(i\xi)\tilde{f}(\xi)
\end{align*}
Then in this case the two definitions are consistent, but
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty e^{-i\xi t} \partial_t^2 e^{-kt}\, dt \ne (i\xi)^2 \frac{1}{k+i\xi}.
\end{align*}
So, if we know only (1) how can I find (2)? Or viceversa if I know (2) how can I find (1)? If one of the two is true also the other is true?

The problem is that Fourier transform and Fourier transform on half-line (or the Laplace transform) are not equivalent, but I would like to understand how the operator defined in (1) acts on $e^{-kt}$ for $t>0$. Can someone help me? Thanks to everybody, each comment can be valuable

Comment: Can $k$ be a complex number in your second definition?

Comment: Yes, $k$ could be complex

Comment: So (2) essentially gives you an action of the operator on a orthogonal basis?

Comment: First of all thanks for your time. I have $k=\sqrt{-x \ i}$,  where $i$ is imaginary unit and $x$ is real, or in general $k= f (-ix)$. So $k$ can be a function of $-i \ x$, but my focus is on the operator in $t$, $t>0$. I've always worked with Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$ or with Laplace transform on $(0,\infty)$, so I'm not so familiar with orthogonal basis, can you suggest me something and how Fourier transform acts on it? Also notes or books would be useful, thanks again!